# Laravel eloquent sortBy and OrderBy

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have to tables related.

Productos

- ID
- Nombre

SubProductos (child table)

- ID
- Nombre
- Producto_Id

I need to sort by Producto.Nombre and then SubProducto.Nombre

It is a combination of:

$subProductos = SubProducto::with('producto')->get()->sortBy('producto.nombre');

and

$subProductos = SubProducto::orderBy('nombre', 'ASC')->get();

Any help? Thanks!

Model Producto.php

```
class producto extends Model
{
    public function SubProductos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Certifier\SubProducto');
    }
}
```

Model SubProducto.PHP

```
class SubProducto extends Model
{
    public function EmpresaSubProductos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Certifier\EmpresaSubProducto');
    }
    public function producto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Certifier\Producto');
    }
    public function subProductoFormateado() {
        return $this->producto->nombre . ' - ' . $this->nombre;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some advices, your functions should beggan with lowercase leters and your classes with uppercase leters

I edited the code:

```
$productos= producto::with(array('SubProductos'=>function($query){
         $query->orderBy('nombre', 'ASC');
     }))
->orderBy('nombre')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. Appears an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'"

Comment: SubProductos is the child table. I need to query all the subproductos.

Comment: like i said, change "subProductos" word for whatever you name the function that make the relation between productos and subproductos.

Comment: if you dont understand what i said show us your models code and we help you

Comment: I added the models

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160024/discussion-between-leonardo-cabre-and-jpussacq).

Comment: Finally I found a solution. I did not understand part of my own solution, but it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[There are a few hacky solutions on the issue page about this in Laravel.](https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/11) I think that a callback combining all of the fields you want as suggested in the first comment there may do the trick.

Comment: I tried this $subProductos = SubProducto::with('producto')->get()->sortBy('producto.nombre')->sortBy('SubProducto.nombre'); but not working the second "nombre"

Answer (score 1):

I assume you were sorting them as a View in blade.php

Begin with your Controller just simply define `$productos` items

```
// retrieving productos from Model
$productos = producto::orderBy('nombre')->get()->all();

return view( 'your.blade.view' )->with( [ 'productos' => $productos ] );
```

In the blade.php you display `$productos` like this

```
<ul class="list-producto">
@foreach( $productos as $producto )
   <li class="producto">
       <span>{{ $producto->nombre }}</span>
       @if( $productos->sub_productos )
           <ul class="list-sub-producto">
           @foreach( $productos->sub_productos->sortBy('nombre')->all() as $sub_producto )
               <li class="sub-producto">
                   <span>{{ $producto->nombre }} - {{ $sub_producto->nombre }}</span>
               </li>
           @endforeach
           </ul>
       @endif
   </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

As a note, you should replace `class producto` with `class Producto` because a Model usually using [studly_case](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-studly-case).

Answer (score 0):

Solved using that:

```
$subProductos = SubProducto::selectRaw('sub_productos.*, productos.nombre as nombre_producto')
  ->join('productos', 'productos.id', '=', 'sub_productos.producto_id')
  ->orderBy('productos.nombre', 'ASC')
  ->orderBy('sub_productos.nombre', 'ASC')
  ->get();
```

Not sure why, but this was the key:

$subProductos = SubProducto::selectRaw('sub_productos.*, **productos.nombre as nombre_producto**')